# Set Auto width - jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How do I set auto width in jQuery auto-complete option?

```
$('#'+pmId).autocomplete('mst_get_masterinfo.php?vValid=15&vRetType=1&vCategory='+vCatCode,{
      delay:10,
      cacheLength: 0,
      width:200,// Width Option
      mustMatch:true,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've ever did this using the `open` option, which is triggered after the menu has been opened.

```
$('#'+pmId).autocomplete('mst_get_masterinfo.php?vValid=15&vRetType=1&vCategory='+vCatCode,{
    delay:10,
    cacheLength: 0,
    mustMatch:true,
    open: function() { 
        // After menu has been opened, set width to 100px
        $('.ui-menu')
            .width(100);
    }  
});
```

Comment: Hi I just want to show my auto suggest result in every single line. According to the result the width will automatically increase . I don't want to give the width option directly .. suggest me

Comment: Finally I  modified jquery.autocomplete.js file and set width:auto

Comment: Didnt got it, sorry. Do you mean to auto size the `ui-menu`? If so, use `$('.ui-menu').width('auto');` in the `open` callback.

Comment: In open call doesnot work perfetly so I modified main autocomplete.js file && set the width directly

Comment: width: typeof options.width == "string" || options.width > 0 ? options.width : 'auto',

Comment: May you pleased enough to create a [jsFiddle](jsfiddle.net] with an example there the `open` call-approach wont work? Because its very bad design to edit the plugin itself. Better would be a new plugin which wrap's the existing one and supports the `width` option. But I'm confused because often used the `open` callback to adjust the menu without any problems.

Comment: Hi.. I revert the plugin code and I used open function but its not working.I just want to display my result with single line.Don't want to give the width directly .

Comment: My auto suggestion Result -- "16100099A096-CONTRACTORS   RECOVERIES","00007A043-CONTRACTORS   RECOVERIES"  While I search my keyword the "RECOVERIES" displayed in second line . I don't want this